# 7gb .DMG file, only 986mb?

Tags: windows-7, dmg-image

I have a .DMG file of around 7GB.

When I try and open it using Ultra ISO or Magic ISO it just sees it as a 986MB file?

I would love to burn this to a USB key or something, but obviously it wont boot at the moment as it's missing the essential files (is it partitioned?)

Can anyone shed some light? Am using Windows 7.

Comment: Can those tools see everything inside a dmg file? Mount the image on a Mac to see what's really inside.

Answer (score 1):

Disk Images can be larger than what they actually contain.

Think of a CD-ROM with a capacity of 650-800 MB: You can burn a 4kb text file on them and be done with it.

Answer (score -1):

It's a [sparse image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_image), as I'm unaware of any DVD software for Windows aware of this (but do double check) you have to burn it on a mac, or at least turn it into an iso. And I think you have to bless it (either for OSX to run, or for a Mac to run it), which is Mac only as well.

Comment: Sparse images only take up as much space as the data within it is using. I think the op is saying that the file is 7 gb but the contents are less than 1 gb.

Comment: Sparse images have a corresponding file extension anyway.